# Who is Shani and is there a connection with Saturday?

Tags: shani

Who is Shani and is there a connection with Saturday ?

I am living in India for three months and have heard the name mentioned a few times.

Today I saw a man in orange robes and was told he was asking for donations for Shani as it was Saturday. I don't know if this is true but it is what I was told.

Answer (score 3):

Shani is Planet and Indian weekday name.  Saturn in English name of Shani planet and English weekday name Saturday

Saturday same as Shanivara in India

All planets name we refer as week day name & Gods or Devata

**Monday**

- Middle English – Monday or mone(n)day In India  we called Moon as Soma & Chandra. so Monday in India Somvara

**Tuesday**

- Middle English – tiwesday or tewesday & In Latin – dies Martis – “Day of Mars”. In India we Called Mars as Mangal. so Tuesday In India Mangalvara

**Wednessday**

- Middle English – wodnesday or wednesday or wednesdai & In Latin – dies Mercurii – “Day of Mercury”. In India we called Mercury as Budha. so Wednesday In India Budhvara

**Thrusday**

- Middle English – thursday or thuresday & In Latin – dies Jovis – “Day of Jupiter” In India we called Jupiter as Guru. so Thrusday In India Guruvara

**Friday**

- Middle English – “Fridai” & In latin  – “dies Veneris”– Day of Venus. In India we called Venus as Shukra. so Friday In India Shukravara

**Saturday**

- Middle English – Saterday & In latin – dies Saturni – “Day of Saturn”. In india we called Saturn as Shani. so Saturday In india Shanivara.

**Sunday**

- Middle English – Sone(n)dayor Sun(nen)day & In Latin – dies solis– “Day of the sun”. In india we called sun as Surya or ravi. so sunday In India Ravivara

And In India all planets we called them  gods or devta. we have temple also for these planet.

so that man is asking for donation for shani dev temple

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, the correct word is SANISCHARA, i.e., on who moves slowly.

If we take it as a planet, still this meaning holds good. In astrology, the Saturn is the slowest moving planet.

In ancient times, the we do not find week days. In those days, Muhurta, i.e., auspicious time, Nakshatra,i.e, favourable Star, Thithi, i.e., the movement of Moon are being considered.

Week days were imported to this land may be by the British (or) other Western merchants.

Comment: First if all, you should cite sources.  Second of all, the notion of weekdays was definitely there.  In the Sankalpam that you say before any Vedic ritual, you have to specific the place you're doing the ritual and the time and date of the ritual.  In the course of that you specify the Vasara or day of the week.  Like if it's Tuesday you say "Bhauma Vasara Yuktayam."

Comment: This tradition of Sankalpa is very recent.  In Srimad Ramayana, which closely followed the Vedic way of life, gives only the narration of Muhurta, Nakshtra and Thidhi, but not Vaara

Comment: Well, day of the week wasn't used to specify time and date of birth, so there wasn't much opportunity to discuss days of the week in the Ramayana.  In any case, notion of Vasaras is mentioned in plenty of ancient works on Jyotisha (astrology).  So it's not correct to say "In ancient times, we do not find week days."

Comment: I am not well versed in scriptures, as you are.  I do not know the period in which those Astrological books were written.  I have quoted what I read.  There were plenty of opportunities available for Sage Valmiki, if he was aware of Week days, to mention in his epic.  For Example:  (1) While starting for a war Ravana, Sri Rama mentioned about Nakshtra only.  (2)  While passing away Jataayu mentions about the Muhuurta - VINDA , only, but not week days and other angas of Panchanga